# How to use SQLite with Slick

Tags: sqlite, slick

I've changed the conf to below:

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC 
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:db/db.db"
```

and add:

```
"org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.15-M1"
```

but the generated sql is wrong:

```
create table "user" ("uid" BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"name" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,"pw" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,"email" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,"comment" VARCHAR(254),"updateAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,"createAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

because `bigint` can not be auto-incremented.

I don't want to fix it by hand.
how to fix it.
the errors:

```
We got the following error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) [ERROR:1, SQLSTATE:null]
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/07JBbnZ5VZk

Comment: Please cross-link, when you cross-post! Also posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/scalaquery/07JBbnZ5VZk/7D1_5N4uGjsJ

Answer (score 0):

@szeiger wrote here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/07JBbnZ5VZk

> > We got the following error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) [ERROR:1, SQLSTATE:null]
>
> After rereading the SQLite data type documentation, I think mapping *all* ingegral types to INTEGER should be the right course of action because SQLite does not distinguish between them anyway, except for AUTOINCREMENT, where you must call the type INTEGER. It should be as simple as this: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/908.